# would a surge protector with an appliance that might be shorting, protect my house circuit?

Tags: electrical

I have a Playstion with a composite RCA connection that gets hot from the ps3 exhaust.  I think it killed the power to my apartment when a subwoofer flashed and went boom.  I turned the ps3 back on within a minute, as the loss of power didn't last, and it blacked out a portion of my building for an hour, i think.  Would a surge protector help the apartment if that was accurate??

The game stores are closed so i cant get a new cord :(

Comment: FYI, surge protectors only provide some protect to the things you plug into them. They won't do anything for the rest of the house. As jwh20 mentioned, they can and do fail after enough hits. Sometimes one is all it takes to destroy the protector.

Comment: I have many doubts about how to understand your post. How can a subwoofer flash; what does that even mean? Did the subwoofer just make a sound, or what do you mean by "bang"? Does that subwoofer have anything to do with the PS3? Is the subwoofer in your apartment? What "cord" do you want to buy? An RSA cable? If its the exhaust air that makes the RSA cable hot then why do you even think that replacing that cable will help; the new cable will get hot too?  Or by "cord" are you talking about buying a power bar with built in surge protector?

Comment: Was there one or two blackouts? I think I spent significantly more time writing this comment than you did writing your post asking people for help. Sincerely.

Comment: "surge protectors only provide some protect to the things you plug into them" I'm not so sure; why wouldn't it work both ways? I think that it's likely that the surge protector does work in both directions and maybe more accurate is that the PS3 or other devices usually can't produce a power surge.

Comment: i think that your post is complete nonsense ... do you honestly believe that your PS3 knocked out power in a portion of your building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have something else, and that something else is SERIOUS, that has nothing to do with your surge protector.

Yes, a surge protector can caused a short circuit if the active portion of it, in almost all cases a device called a MOV or Metal Oxide Varistor.  A MOV is designed to do nothing when the voltage across it is "normal" but to conduct electricity when the voltage is too high.  The problem is that the MOV literally sacrifices itself to protect whatever is plugged into it.  Usually there is a circuit breaker on the surge protector that is designed to trip when the MOV activates.

Over time the MOV wears out from this "abuse" and it may develop a permanent short which renders the entire surge protector useless and it should be replaced.  Note that is may also fail "silently" where the MOV no longer conducts at high voltage and the entire surge suppressor doesn't do what you expect it to do.

This does NOT appear to be what's going on here, however. Even if it were totally shorted out, which is not what you're describing, it would only trip the circuit breaker that it's plugged into, not the entire apartment.  (That is assuming your apt. has more than one circuit in it.)

It sounds like you have a more general wiring problem and you should get your landlord to hire an electrician to investigate it before more of your electronic devices get damaged or someone get injured.